# need to wipe my hard drive from crashed windows 7 to install Ubuntu

Tags: installation, command-line

Trashed Windows 7 hardrive. Trying to install Ubuntu 13. Need to wipe hardrive but having no success with search items on line. Call me stupid but can't I just do it from the command prompt with some simple command?  I'm in Ubuntu 13 right now as a trial run on the trashed HP G62 i3 64 hard drive unit. Any suggestions?

Comment: It is somewhat unclear what you mean with "trashed". Did you experience a hard drive failure, or do we have an accidentally messed up Windows installation here?

Comment: Hard drive failure. Attempted recovery with no success. Hard drive 'C' is inaccessible, 'D' has HP Recovery intact but also inaccessible. PC Inspector, Recuva, Esaus Recovery have all failed to 'see' hard drive. Have tried various 'shred' commands with limited success. End of day--can't install Ubuntu 13 because it can't write to the hard drive. Need to just wipe the drive and start over which seems relatively easy if I just knew how. Thx.

Comment: You may have to replace the disk rather than reformatting. The drive may stop working any time.

Comment: Say it isn't so! There must be a way to wipe this thing and/or tell me why it can't be done just short of dismantling the drive and investigating it on my own.

Comment: Also, in an attempt to mount the file system with type EXT2 in SCSI 1 (0,0,0) @ /boot....that also failed.

Comment: See additional comment below for final solution. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to delete everything in you HDD? Ok. Boot into your Live-CD or USB, and select **Try Ubuntu** then, press the **Super key** and type in **Gparted**... Open it, and select the HDD you want to wipe, and select **Delete the selected partition**...

There you go, if this wasn't helpful, could you explain a little bit more your problem?

Comment: I found the Super key and did as asked.....screen says 'no matches found'

Comment: Are you sure? Gparted is isntalled by default in the LiveUSB or CD...

Comment: Tried it several times...pretty sure. I can get to the terminal...I just need the proper command. (new to Linux)

Comment: I agree that gpart should be part of the Live dvd install as has been indicated by several people. However, there may be something else going on. Surely someone has got to have a 'go around' for this.

Comment: Perhaps not being able to see the hard drive is cause for the 'no-match', hence the need to 'wipe'....just saying.

Comment: FYI--I found the 'go around' and it failed as well. Looks like this hard drive will become another victim of the target range next week. Skeet is always more exciting with hard drives over clay pigeons.